# How to make custom hotkeys?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, interface

Is there a way to make a custom hotkey for specific functions?
Like to solve my problem here:
I’m working on a piece, its a replica and I have many references setup in some collections and I need to hide/unhide the collections all the time. I do it by hitting the relevant checkbox in the object browser list. Can I somehow hotkey that specific checkbox?
If coding, IK how to code, but I do not know how to get console or script in blender, or at-least I need a ‘pointer’ to get started.

Comment: Press H to hide the collection.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.hide_collection

Comment: Ahh cool ty for api docs, ill look at that stuff ty. Also, h to hide collection doesnt work when im in edit mode and cant select collection (and I want no touching mouse so no selecting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom shortcut directly on most commands, using the assign Shortcut option.

In this case select the collection, press on the context menu (<kbd>F3</kbd>) look for the command and right click. A new menu will allow you to assign a shortcut directly.

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is perfect, many thanks!